# QML/QT Best Practices, for desktop application?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qml, qtcore

I am designing a desktop application to do many things! One involves an initial setup that you have to do once, while the rest is loaded in through AWS, once that one time configuration is done. Coming from a web developer background, I am very used to creating new states throughout an application.

I feel though I would be doing wrong and not following a standard that seems to have been set in QT/QML. Right now I am scaffolding my app to use multiple QML files with .ui.qml files in each one + passing the engine (QQmlApplicationEngine) as a raw pointer throughout my application. My application plans to have multiple different views and states based on data. What would be the right approach in this situation? one single QML with multiple windows to load? or am I on the right track?

Comment: please go through this official [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-bestpractices.html) from Qt

Comment: @RamkumarR I've gone through that already, but I am really looking for a personal experience and tidbits that might not be evident in the documentation. Sometimes the documentation might not have the best interest, to what you might be trying to do.

Comment: Here is a blog [post](https://medium.com/e-fever/revised-qml-application-architecture-guide-with-flux-a1de143fe13e) which gives guidance to design qml application architecture. This blog gives an idea to design the app based on Facebook's flux architecture. Since you are coming from a web development background hope this may be a good start for you.